# A Tetrahedric topology in Blender

Tags: mesh, topology

I did a simple mesh of twisted yarn, I am supposed to use this mesh for FEM simulation in SOFA software. In order to be being able to deform the mesh, I must have a discrete version of its volume which is VTK mesh.

I am using GMSH, and I got the following error: the mesh doesn't have a Tetrahedric topology: this means that I have a problem in the mesh at blender, I don't know what is the problem, here the files:

Here is the OBJ file:https://gofile.io/?c=X0Hm6U

Here the VTK file: https://gofile.io/?c=gFZfJ0

[image]

I would be grateful for help in figuring out the mistake in the mesh.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe triangulation will help (select everything and press CTRL+T) Also mesh seems to have inverted normals (judging by the dark color), so do CTRL-N to make them consistent.

Comment: @SergeL, I think i still do have the issue of inverted normals, could you please give me insights what could be wrong https://gofile.io/?c=uPa2xM